# Why does this Ruby Kata return 0 instead of 2?

Tags: ruby

I have this code which should return the number of trailing zeros of a number. The code I have returns 0 when it should return 2. Not quite sure what is happening. Some help guys?

```
def trailing_zeros(number)
  sort_sum = number.to_s.split(//).reverse
  counter = 0
  until sort_sum[counter] == "0"
    counter += 1
    return counter
  end
end
```

----------EDIT------------

I've removed the return counter from inside my until loop and still get no result.

```
  def trailing_zeros(number)
    sort_sum = number.to_s.split(//).reverse
    counter = 0
    until sort_sum[counter] == "0"
      counter += 1
    end
    return counter
  end
```

If I put in 1200, I'm supposed to get 2, but I keep getting 0

-----------EDIT--------

Hey guys, I have one more question. So I'm trying to understand why the above function and this new function I have doesn't work.

```
def zeros(n)
  trailing_zeros(n) if n == 1
  zeros(n-1) * n
end

def trailing_zeros(number)
  sort_sum = number.to_s.split(//).reverse
  counter = 0
  until sort_sum[counter] != "0"
    counter += 1
  end
  return counter
```

end

puts zeros(12)

I also keep getting a zero for this input and I'm just not sure why. At first it was because I thought the trailing zeros function needed to be defined by zero, but then I just get a stack level too deep error. When I use require pry and look at this line:

```
trailing_zeros(n) if n == 1
```

A zero is always passed into it. I feel frustrated because I should know my basics by this point. An additional, question. What constitutes a stack level too deep error?

Comment: using `return counter` inside your loop will exit the method before the loop is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't `return` the counter within your loop.

Let the loop finish and then return the final `counter`.

Moreover, you are using `until` erroneously. `until` will execute it's body for as long as the condition is **false** (i.e. `puts 'a' until false` will run infinitely). Your condition is from the beginning **true** when you pass it any number with trailing 0s (as you reverse the string version of the number), thus, your `until` exits immediately.

Why not try that instead (based on your approach but a bit more Rubyish):

```
def trailing_zeros(number)
  sort_sum = number.to_s.split(//).reverse  

  counter = 0

  sort_sum.each do |num|
    num == '0' ? counter += 1 : break
  end

  counter
end
```

Comment: It would still be 1 not 0

Comment: If we can rewrite I'd just do `number.to_s[/0*$/].size` instead :)

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers Absolutely! But being a "Kata" I didn't want to change the OP's approach completely, just handle his way of thinking in a more Ruby style.

Answer (score 2):

```
def trailing_zeros(number)
  sort_sum = number.to_s.split(//).reverse
  counter = 0
  until sort_sum[counter] != "0"
    counter += 1
  end
  counter
end
```

Move return out of loop
Change ==0 to !=0  You want to stop when you run out of zeros.

Answer (score 0):

The initial for sort)sum[counter] may be "0" in this case your loop never runs and the last computed value is returned which is your initialization of counter to 0 so it makes sense. To clarify your loop is never running

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is:

```
until sort_sum[counter] == "0"
```

which translates into "until you hit a 0" in the array. If your input is 1200, `sort_sum[counter] == "0"` is evaluated to `true` **the first time**, never entering your loop.

To do this without looping in Ruby, consider:

```
def trailing_zeros(number)
  number.to_s.split(//).reverse.find_index{|digit| digit != "0"}
end
```

which finds the first entry in the array of digits that is not zero (see [Enumberable#find_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_index)).